# Unable to save form using django.views.generic.View

Tags: python, django, forms

I was able to save before without an issue using django.views.generic.CreateView. However, I can't save the same form using View.

Below are my codes:

models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Project Name')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, 
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             blank=True,
                             null=True)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client,
                               on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                               blank=True,
                               null=True)
    deadline = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import View

class ProjectCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):

    form_class = ProjectCreateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('dashboard')
    template_name = 'translation/project_form.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        project_form = self.form_class(request.POST, instance=request.user)
       
        if project_form.is_valid():
            project_form.save()
            return redirect(self.success_url)
        else:
            return render(request, self.template_name)
```

html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container mt-5 py-2 w-50 bg-dark text-white">
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form|crispy }}
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mt-3">Confirm</button>
    </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

urls.py

```
    path('project/new', views.ProjectCreateView.as_view(), name='project-add'),
```

When I submit the form in html, it doesn't render any error message. It simply redirects to the `self.success_url` and the intended object is not saved.

Any help or advice will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Edit:

Forgot to include the codes for the Form:

forms.py

```
class ProjectCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        widgets = {
            'deadline' : forms.DateInput(attrs={'type':'date'})
        }
        fields = ['name', 'client', 'deadline']
```

Comment: Can you share the code for `ProjectCreateForm`? It looks to me like your view should work so maybe the issue is with the form.

Comment: @DJRamones I meant to include all codes related to the issue but forgot to include the forms :(  It's in the edit now. Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain what you trying to do here `    `project_form = self.form_class(request.POST, instance=request.user)` with `request.user`?

Comment: Okay, so your form isn't doing anything special, so I still have no idea why it's not working. At this point, if I were you I'd dig deeper by looking at what the HTTP request being received by the view looks like, the variables at play, and then maybe get debugging info at the point of execution of the `project_form.save()` line.

Comment: @DJRamones, thanks! I looked into what the form is saving by adding something like print(project_form.__dict__). The inputs made at the html side all come through properly though. I'll give it another go later today so if anything works, I'll post a comment. :) Thank you

Comment: @AzyCrw4282, thanks for the comment! I added ```instance=request.uesr``` because the Project object being made a foreign key connected to User, ie. each Project has a field for the user to created the project. *similar to blog articles

Comment: Hey guys. Yea, so like @AzyCrw4282 mentioned, it was actually the ```instance=request.user``` that was causing the problem. I got rid of that part and set the form fields so that the user will have to set the ```user``` field manually and the Project form saves now. It's annoying not to be able to allow the user to have his user.id attached to the Project's User foreignkey field but that's another problem for another day. Thank you for your support!